# How to add (custom) widgets to allure 2.10.x?

Tags: widget, allure

i was looking at the allure documentation to figure out how to add a widget to the overview tab of the allure report. Unfortunately the part including how to do this isn't up to date any more. Hope someone is able to give me an example.

i couldn't use the example in the documentation because it's deprecated.

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: Did you get any way to get this done?